# How Can I Animate The Significant Blurring of a Sprite

Tags: ipad, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I am using Cocos2d on the iPad to create a small game. I would like to, purposely, significantly blur a sprite, and then fade it out.

Particularly, I was hoping to make a sprite containing text get blurry (like the ink was fading or soaking into the paper) and then ultimately disappear, as if by magic.

I know how to animate the fade process using Cocos2D actions.

How can I animate the process of a sprite becoming super blurry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to do a blur effect with the default cocos2d actions/functions.

you might want to try this custom gaussian blur class out instead

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6315

the code is in the middle of the thread

or a more troublesome alternative is to create the blur effect using frame by frame animation

Comment: Thanks Treon. I had found that post, and hoped there was an easier way.